# How can I make a text box that changes it's fore color based on what's entered in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I'd like to have a text input box that set's the fore color of the text to black if the number is 0 or greater, and red if it's below 0. This is the code I've got so far, and it's entered under the text box event handler for "TextChanged" so that it'll run every time the text changes. Here is the code,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength > 1)
        {
            valueCheck = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        }
        if (valueCheck < 1)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (valueCheck > 0)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        valueCheck = 0;
    }
```

The problem comes when I enter one number of any kind, it's red. But when I enter a second positive number, it turns black. I'm not quite sure what's going on, I think it might have something to do with the way the code is validating on every pass. If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Remove your last `else` block.

Comment: And what happens when you set a breakpoint in this handler on the second pass?

Comment: Can you show more code? This looks like typing `3` should work. Does it?

Comment: removing the last else block doesn't work unfortunately, and that's really all the code I have for this. I'll post the rest of the class, but it just includes the declaration of valueCheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if (textBox1.TextLength > 1)

When you enter 1 number of any kind, the length of textBox1 is not greater than 1, so valueCheck is not being set.

Also Convert.ToInt32 can throw exceptions in the case where the user only enters the  ( - ) sign.

```
     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int valueCheck = 0;
        if (textBox1.TextLength >= 1)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out valueCheck);
        }
        if (valueCheck < 1)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (valueCheck > 0)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        valueCheck = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, however you're definitely right about the Convert.ToInt32 throwing an exception on a "-". What I did was made use of a check box that can determine whether or not the value is negative, if the checkbox is checked, then the fore color is set to red, otherwise, it's black

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement will only set `valueCheck` if `TextLength` is greater than 1, not greater than 0.

Example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.TextLength != 0) // more than 0 characters
    {
        valueCheck = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    }

    if (valueCheck >= 0) // Greater/Equal than 0, Black
    {
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else // less than 0, Red
    {
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    valueCheck = 0;
}
```

or

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.TextLength != 0)
    {
        valueCheck = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    }
    textBox1.ForeColor = valueCheck >= 0 Color.Black : Color.Red
    valueCheck = 0;
}
```